# Do not know what program to open a Sublime 2 file with

Tags: ruby

I have a Windows and I'm using Ruby 1.9.1-p429, and it won't allow me to view my test.rb file on cmd when i type cd. I'll go through step-by-step of what I did.

I saved a test .rb file on Sublime to my desktop. I open cmd and type "cd", expecting it to list the test.rb file, as the About.com tutorial said it would. Nothing shows up.

I go to the files on my desktop and open it. It says I need a program to open it with. I try opening it with Ruby Interactive. Nothing. The same thing happens when i try to open it with cmd. Now all the save files try to open it with cmd.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It really sounds like you don't understand how to use your operating system; These are basic skills you are talking about. `cd` means "change directory", and only is used to change from one directory and make another the default directory. `dir` is the command used to list files.

Comment: `cd` doesn't list files - `dir` does

Comment: Why are you using Ruby 1.9.1? That version is woefully out of date and wasn't entirely production ready. 1.9.2 or better is a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby files should be opened with `ruby.exe`, wherever that is on your system.

Comment: I try to open a file using Ruby.exe, and the screen opens for a split second and then shuts off. I am aware that this version of Ruby is outdated by I was instructed to use it by About.com through instructions for App Academy.